# SQL SERVER 2017 | error al restaurar Base de Datos | Ningún conjunto de copia de seguridad seleccionado para ser restaurado

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2017

Tengo un problema al intentar restaurar una base de datos,
desde que entro a la ventana de restaurar base de datos me sale un error diciéndome:
"Ningún conjunto de copia de seguridad seleccionado para ser restaurado".
Sin ningún motivo me muestra este problema.

Sí selecciono mi bd no me deja proceder a la restauración, sigue el mismo mensaje de error.

¿Cómo lo soluciono?
¿a que se debe el problema?

Saludos!

Aquí una captura, del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que veo en la imágen que subes, tienes seleccionada la opción `Database`, la cual sirve para restaurar desde un Servidor SQL diferente al tuyo o desde una instancia diferente o desde otra base de datos en la misma instancia. Si lo que deseas es restaurar desde un archivo `.bak`, debes seleccionar la opción `Device` y agregar la ruta a dicho archivo presionando el botón `•••` que se habilitará. Sin más información de la que proporcionas no sabría qué más aportar. Saludos

Comment: Es un tema muy raro. Yo requiero montar una BD para pruebas a partir de una de producción. He realizado el respaldo de mi BD productiva en el Manejador (SQL 2014) y ahí mismo he intentado restaurarlo (desde dispositivo)... al final me marca el mismo error que a ustedes. También he intentado hacerlo con la opción "BD origen" y "BD destino" y el resultado es el mismo :(
Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Este mensaje de error a veces suele presentarse cuando estas tratando de restaurar un backup hecho en una versión de SQL Server superior a la versión de SQL Server en que se encuentra la instancia de base de datos donde deseas resturar el backup. No se puede restaurar un backup en una versión de SQL Server menor a la versión de SQL Server que hizo el backup.

Trata de usar la siguiente instrucción Transact-SQL para que se te revelen un mensaje con mayor detalle de qué está ocurriendo y cuál es la causa del error:
I had this problem and it turned out I was trying to restore to the wrong version of SQL.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [NombreTuBaseDeDatos] 
FROM DISK='<ruta donde se encuentra el archivo de backup>\<ElNombreDelArchivoDeBackup>.bak'
```

Otra posible causa es falta de permisos para leer el archivo o el archivo no se encuentra en la ruta especificada. Pon el archivo en la siguiente ruta y trata de restaurar indicando el archivo en esta nueva ruta: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup. También trata de otorgar permisos adecuados para que la cuenta de servicio de SQL Server pueda tener el permiso de leer el archivo de backup.

Una solución alterna también suele ser cerra SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) y abrirlo como Administrador ([Ejecutar como Administrador](https://www.pcworld.es/tutoriales/software/ejecutar-programa-administrador-windows-10-3689587/)).

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso seleccioné el archivo de respaldo, de extensión .bak, en la opción de Device (Dispositivo) pero de igual manera me aparece el mensaje:

> No se seleccionó ningún conjunto de copias de seguridad para
>   restaurarlo.

Si utilizo el comando de T-SQL para comprobar la integridad del archivo de respaldo

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='C:\Ruta_del_archivo\Nombre_del_archivo.Bak'
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

> El archivo del dispositivo
>   'C:\Ruta_del_archivo\Nombre_del_archivo.Bak' no es un conjunto de
>   copia de seguridad válido con formato de cinta de Microsoft.

Por lo que otra de las razones de que no se restaure la base de datos es porque el archivo del respaldo está dañado.